# MySQL get the number of rows in an innodb table

Tags: mysql, count, innodb

I have a table using innodb. I know the table has roughly 89 million rows. Using

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table;
```

takes about five minutes to run. I know that innodb is not optimized for unconditional COUNT(*) queries. How can I restructure the query to give me a count faster? Would just adding WHERE 1=1 work, or do I need to query a specific field?

I know I can get the approximate number of rows using SHOW TABLE STATUS, but I want to get the value in a PHP script, and it seems like there is a lot to dig through using that method.

Comment: See also: http://www.tocker.ca/2013/05/02/fastest-way-to-count-rows-in-a-table.html

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you are OK with the estimated number and just don't want to mess with running `SHOW TABLE STATUS` from PHP, you can use the information_schema DB:

```
SELECT TABLE_ROWS FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_db_name' 
AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table_name';
```

Comment: I'm curious as to how this is "estimated." Could someone provide me with more information on that? Why wouldn't this number be completely accurate? Thanks.

Comment: @MMiller - You can read all about it here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/innodb-other-changes-statistics-estimation.html

Comment: +1 Very good for when we need not use `WHERE`. If you use `WHERE`, maybe a `SELECT count (1)` is the best outlet (I do not know if this makes a buffer of all lines displayed).

Comment: @Pacerier - of course. This answer is an optional optimization if an estimation is OK. Otherwise there  is no escaping a full table scan (AFAIK)

Answer (score 8):

If you are ok with approximate number of records, you can use output of "`explain`".

Simplified verion of the code is

```
$result = mysql_query('explain SELECT count(*) from TABLE_NAME');
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['rows'];
```

Comment: Much easier and seems to show the same number as information_schema.tables, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If the table is read frequently and updated infrequently, you may want to consider creating a statistics table that is updated via [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) when making changes to the table.

Answer (score -6):

mysql_num_rows may be useful to you.

Comment: Doesn't that just give the number of rows in a buffered result set? I am looking for the number of rows in the full table.