# Quickly estimate number of rows scanned by a query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Is there a way to estimate (quickly) the number of rows that will be scanned by a query in MySQL.

Using EXPLAIN seems to give some indication of how many rows in the 'rows' field that is returned. This seems to work fairly well with a select against a single table: for filters against indexed columns, the EXPLAIN 'rows' field is similar to what you get from count(*) against the query.

For joins, I would think taking the product of all of the 'row's would give something similar (or higher than) the number of returned rows, but the product of the 'row's often gives a value much lower than what you get by count(*); I've noticed it lower by a factor of 100.

Any thoughts on how to efficiently do this for arbitrary queries?

Comment: Read first answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120075/mysql-get-the-number-of-rows-in-an-innodb-table).This show you how to retrieve FAST the ESTIMATED number of rows in any table. And beside that, waht you are trying to achive is completely unclear, its up to MySQL to choose the right paths for the query plans, you don't have to code this yourself... You might have to provide HINTS to get the right plan, but at no moment you  have to evaluate the number of rows in your tables by yourself, to choose the best amongst several queries, if that's what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Thomas running a count query against a query that scans 50 million rows can be quite slow. Having a fast estimate of how many rows would be scanned would inform of the cost of running the count(*) query. This is useful, so algorithms aren't doing costly counts.

Comment: @Thomas Also I had already read that post you linked to. One can do that, or use the cardinality from the primary key to get the estimate of the total number of rows in the table. I was hoping for an estimate from the query planner for the number of rows to be scanned.